# Unable to register the DLL/OCX: RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0x5

Tags: dll, ocx, regsvr32, msxml4

I want to install the latest TeXnicCenter on Windows 7 Professional (64-Bit). But everytime I run the installer with admin rights I get the message:

"C:\Windows\system32\msxml4.dll

Unable to register the DLL/OCX: RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0x5. Click Retry to try again, Ignore to proceed anyway (not recommended), or Abort to cancel installation."

The file "C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe" is existing and an integrity check with Microsoft's sfc.exe was successful.

What can I do now? Help would be nice.